# Python slicing from last to first element?

Tags: python, tuples, slice

so i have a tuple in python and i need to slice from the last element to first element but only want the last and first...

example:

big tuple: (1,2,3,4,5)

i want to slice the tuple so i end up with (5,1)

```
some_list[::len(some_list)-1]
```

above code slices from first to last and only includes the first and last..taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218796/python-slice-first-and-last-element-in-list)!
so i need the exact opposite.

Comment: nevermind just figured it out :D
[-1::-4]) gave me 5,1

Comment: If your tuple has other than 5 elements then your code wouldn't work the way you expect to.

Comment: i can do [-1::-(len(list)-1)] ? that seems to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works:

```
some_list[-1:-len(some_list)-1:-(len(some_list) - 1)]
```

Another way:

```
some_list[::-len(some_list) + 1]
```

Of course you always can do

```
x[::len(x) - 1][::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do

```
new_list = (some_list[-1], some_list[0])
```

?

Comment: while simple indexing is alot easier to read/understand its not what i needed in this case :)

Comment: You also haven't told us what exactly you are trying to solve and why are you doing what you are doing, so that's answers you might get.

Comment: yes you are right, i realize this isnt a very helpful question so is there a way to get it deleted?

Comment: It's okay, quite often we are intuitive in a way in pointing out a solution, but as I said without knowing exactly what your data/function override actually are we can't really say for sure that your way is inadequate or other suggested ways are correct.  Still good enough as a reference though.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = (1,2,3,4,5)    
print(a[0],a[-1])
```

Please try this. It has worked for me and seems to be a simple solution.